# Cannot assign column name by indexing within function argument

Tags: r

I am learning R, and I am trying to understand the indexing properties. I cannot seem to understand why the following code to change a column name does not work:

```
state.all <- as.data.frame(state.x77)
head(state.all)
state.all$States <- rownames(state.all)
rownames(state.all) <- NULL
# why the following row does not work?
names(state.all["States"]) <- "Test"
colnames(state.all)
```

While this works:

```
state.all <- as.data.frame(state.x77)
head(state.all)
state.all$States <- rownames(state.all)
rownames(state.all) <- NULL
# This work
names(state.all)[which(colnames(state.all)=="States")] <- "Test"
colnames(state.all)
```

Shouldn't the function be able to overwrite the name of the column also in the first example? Is it something to do with the local vs. global environment?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is replacing the name of column number 9.
the expression `which(colnames(state.all)=="States")` results in the index if the column named "States" (if there is any) and then takes this index and replaces the value in the names vector.
the expression `state.all["States"]` just returns the values of this column so of course nothing will happen.

I suggest something like `colnames(state.all)[which(colnames(state.all)=="States")] <- "Test"`.